# Why do "large" opens of abelian surfaces have "small" canonical bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian surface, and let $S$ be a finite set of points. Let $U=A\setminus S$. Note that $U$ is a "large" open of $A$.

Let $B\to A$ be a proper birational surjective morphism with $B$ smooth projective surface such that $B\to A$ is an isomorphism over $U$, and such that $B\setminus U$ is a divisor, say $D$. (In other words, $B\to A$ is obtained by blowing up $S$ in $A$ in an appropriate fashion.)

> > Why is $\omega_B + D$ not big? Is it trivial?

Comment: $K_B=f^*K_A+E$, where $E$ is an effective $f$-exceptional divisor supported on $D$. Hence $K_B+D$ has same Kodaira dimension as $K_A$ which is $0$. But of course it is not trivial.